# Can I set the scrolling speed when I mouse over the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

Is there a setting to increase the scroll speed of the Unity Panel when using the Mouse.

When in keyboard mode the launcher will scroll quickly, however with the mouse over event action scrolling though a number of panel items at the bottom is too slow

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the three ways to scroll with the Mouse over the Launcher

- Mouse Wheel
- Mouse Cursor at the Top/Bottom will enable Auto-Scrolling
- Click & Drag

There does not appear to be any current way to edit the speed however there is an auto-scroll [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/747874) that might be relevant here.